# jQuery for a beginner Web Designer

Tags: jquery, arguments

What arguments can I use to encourage a beginner Web Designer that jQuery library is worth learning and using? For someone that is proficient in HTML and CSS, with some PHP expertise but with little JavaScript, jQuery appears like a huge risk and a maintenance nightmare.

Presentation articles like these ones published by “Smashing Magazine” :

- [jQuery and JavaScript Coding: Examples and Best Practices](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/16/jquery-examples-and-best-practices/)
- [45+ New jQuery Techniques For Good User Experience](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/15/45-new-jquery-techniques-for-a-good-user-experience/)
- [50 Useful New jQuery Techniques and Tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/23/50-useful-new-jquery-techniques/)

are met with a raised eyebrow – they appear either too gimmicky (e.g. sliding animations), one trick pony (image slideshows)  or complex and difficult to master.

So, what are the biggest benefits in using jQuery (both graphical and functional) – are there any simple examples that prove the concept?

Comment: let designers design and programmers program

Comment: A designer who thinks sliding is too gimmicky?!?! ;)

Comment: How proficient are you? Got an example of your recent work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery isn't really just "some tool" any more. It's utilised throughout many high-tech websites and more often than not a lot of designers are asked if they know jQuery in an interview. Hell, when its on Google and Microsoft's radar you know its an effective standard in Web Design.

To me, Web Design encompasses the client-side aspects of the website development process. If your designer ever has a need to move parts of the problem domain to the client-side then let them try it without JavaScript. I can almost guarantee that the jQuery method of doing the same thing will be far simpler; take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045/what-advantages-does-jquery-have-over-other-javascript-libraries/72737#72737) from another jQuery related question as an example.

I don't agree with the idea that programmers and designers are too far apart to appreciate helpful tools. I have worked within graphic design as well as software development and whilst both fields require a different mindset something like jQuery should be advertised by its main selling point - it'll make your life far easier. If anything else knowledge of jQuery will benefit a beginner web designer by adding another skill to their resume.

That being said, if you can see no real benefit to using jQuery then perhaps you shouldn't use it?

Answer (score 2):

Some things are easier to do with jQuery than CSS. e.g. having expandable block of content with an animated effect, a "modal" dialog etc

jQuery can handle many cross browser issues for you which you would need to handle with different CSS / JavaScript for each browser.

Cross browser AJAX support allowing access to data via XML or JSON web services is also useful.

Adding jQuery to your page is relatively pain free and low impact as you are just adding a reference to a JavaScript file.

The "huge risk and a maintenance nightmare" is somewhat mitigated by a large base of developers who will complain on your behalf or fix it if something in the library isn't working as expected.